# Version 91 of Chrome seems to have cause an issue with rendering the Full Calendar V5

Tags: fullcalendar-5

FullCalendar V5 was working yesterday, but now my chrome browser has updated to version 91 and cannot render the calender, all i am able to see is the resources/users available.

See screenshot attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPJxE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. After i changed the column width from half an hour to 1 hour the problem was gone. unfortunately this is not a solution because i need the column width of half an hour.

it seems that it has to do with slotWidth. i increased the value and while increasing i got more and more area in the calendar that worked. when i left it out almost the complete calendar was shown as it should be except of a small part on the right. Unfortunately this is not the complete solution. i specially lowered the SlotWidth so i could see a complete week on my screen. Which after the chrome update didnt work anymore either. the area that is not working doesnt have the horizontal lines.

before width change
[image: before width change]

after width change
[image: after width change]

Answer (score 0):

This bug was reported and fixed in the latest release 5.7.2

https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/releases/tag/v5.7.2